# Sorting a Python 3 Dictionary by values back to Dictionary not a List of Tuples

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, python-3.5, key-value

I want to sort a dictionary by its values(of integers) back to a Dictionary. Like following :

```
di = {'h': 10, 'e':5, 'l':8}
```

What I want is :

```
sorted_di = {'e':5, 'l':8, 'h':10}
```

I searched a lot and got to sort it into list of tuples, like:

```
import operator
sorted_li = sorted(di.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
print(sorted_li)
```

Gives :

```
[('e',5),('l':8),('h':10)]
```

But I want it to be a dictionary again.

Can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Are dictionaries ordered in Python
>   3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)
>
> They are **insertion ordered**. As of Python 3.6, for the CPython
>   implementation of Python, dictionaries remember the order of items
>   inserted. This is considered an implementation detail in Python 3.6;
>   you need to use `OrderedDict` if you want insertion ordering that's
>   guaranteed across other implementations of Python (and other ordered
>   behavior).

i.e.

- Pre-3.6:

  ```
  >>> from collections import OrderedDict
  ...
  >>> OrderedDict(sorted_li)
  OrderedDict([('e', 5), ('l', 8), ('h', 10)])
  ```
- 3.6+:

  ```
  >>> dict(sorted_li)
  {'e':5, 'l':8, 'h':10}
  ```

Comment: I believe they changed it from an implementation detail to a guarantee in Python 3.7.

Comment: @FightWithCode `OrderedDict` *is* a dictionary, it only *looks* like tuples when you print it.

Comment: Ok now i understand. First of all sort the dict into list of tuples. And then convert it to dict by OrderedDict. Thank-you so much

Comment: @FightWithCode you should include the sorting code in the question body; my answer was meant to describe the next step.

Comment: OK as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
di = {'h': 10, 'e':5, 'l':8}
temp_list = []
for key,value in di.items():
    temp_tuple = (k,v)
    temp_list.append(temp_tuple)
temp_list.sort()
for x,y in temp_list:
    dict_sorted = dict(temp_list)
print(dict_sorted)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on SO. Please supplement the code you have provided as an answer with why it solves OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
di = {'h': 10, 'e':5, 'l':8}
tuples = [(k, di[k]) for k in sorted(di, key=di.get, reverse=False)]
sorted_di = {}
for i in range(len(di)):
    k = tuples[i][0]
    v = tuples[i][1]
    sorted_di.update({k: v})
print(sorted_di)  # {'e': 5, 'l': 8, 'h': 10}
```